# Erro java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - TrataErroClass

Tags: java

Eu estou tento subir uma aplicação feita aqui no trabalho e toda hora que tento rodar no `tomcat` da esse erro. Já dei uma pesquisada e aparentemente fala que a classe está usando outra classe que não está no meu classpayj. Como soluciono isso?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mapl/util/logging/http/TrataErroClass
    at mapl.action.TrataErroAction.<init>(TrataErroAction.java:26)
    at com.dts.actions.v1_1.FrameworkAction.<init>(FrameworkAction.java:27)
    at gcpj.filter.VerificaProcessoBatch.<init>(VerificaProcessoBatch.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3635)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Oct 11, 2018 9:59:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter VerificacaoFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mapl/util/logging/http/TrataErroClass
    at mapl.action.TrataErroAction.<init>(TrataErroAction.java:26)
    at com.dts.actions.v1_1.FrameworkAction.<init>(FrameworkAction.java:27)
    at gcpj.filter.VerificaSessao.<init>(VerificaSessao.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3635)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

Comment: Jovem, edite a pergunta e forneça o código que estoura este erro, senão fica dificil pra te ajudar.

Comment: Ele da esse erro no momento que eu dou um start no tomcat

Comment: Não há informação suficiente na sua pergunta para que uma resposta além daquilo que o Michel Anjos já postou. Se quiser mais detalhes, você poderia informar como é que você constrói seu projeto e quais são os JARs que você tem no classpath/modulepath.

Answer (score 2):

Como bem você falou reclama de uma classe que não está no seu classpath. Pelo stacktrace ví que tem uma classe TrataErroAction.java e na linha 26 chama essa outra classe TrataErroClass.java.

Se estiver usando maven, verifica se estão todas as dependências corretas no pom.xml. Caso não esteja, olha para a pasta lib do seu projeto ou a lib do tomcat.